# Display whatever content this page have to another page using Ajax/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Whats wrong with this code?

Index.cshtml -- has

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main").load('CallScreen.cshtml #content');
});
<div id="main">
   Content Will be here.
</div>
```

CallScreen.cshtml -- has

```
<div id="content">
</div>
```

What I would like to do here is display my content on `<div id=main">` and then display it inside `<div id="content">` from another page `CallScreen.cshtml`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Your code look like it do the opposite purpose, load content of CallScreen.cshtml to #main of Index.cshtml, am I right ?

Comment: yea, looks like it lol.. but when I revised it, still doesnt work? why?

Comment: what should be the proper way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one - I assume you know this but the javascript needs to go into a

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main").load('CallScreen.cshtml #content');
});
</script>
```

tag

Also - make sure you remove the extra space so that 'CallScreen.cshtml #content' is 'CallScreen.cshtml#content'

Your code will inject #content into #main.